# How to assgin a file in a folder as others file owned in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have folder A and B contain of some file. The total of file in those folder is not assign.
I want to  change the name of some file in the folder B and the total file that I want to change depend on the total file in the folder A. The average of folder B if divide by folder A.

Example:

Folder A file (2 Files):

```
ID_12345-ABC.txt
ID_67890-DEF.txt
```

Folder B file (10 Files):

```
NO_1111-A.txt
NO_1111-B.txt
NO_1111-C.txt
NO_1111-D.txt
NO_1111-E.txt
NO_1111-F.txt
NO_1111-G.txt
...
NO_1111-J.txt
```

Then, I want to change the file name in the folder B. This case, I will assign each 5 files  in the folder B to File A.
In the folder B, I will have this file name.

```
12345-ABC_NO_1111-A.txt
12345-ABC_NO_1111-B.txt
12345-ABC_NO_1111-C.txt
12345-ABC_NO_1111-D.txt
12345-ABC_NO_1111-E.txt
67890-DEF_NO_1111-F.txt
67890-DEF_NO_1111-G.txt
...
67890-DEF_NO_1111-J.txt
```

Anyone can give me idea about this case?

Comment: Build a list of the prefixes you want to add to the files in Folder B from the files in Folder A. Then get the files from Folder B into an array and use a `for` loop to change the file names. Assign the prefix depending on the value of the loop counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the following manner:

```
# get an array of prefixes, taken from the file names in FolderA
$prefixes = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\FolderA' -File | ForEach-Object { $_.BaseName -replace '^ID_' } | Sort-Object
# get an array of FileInfo objects of all files in FolderB
$filesB = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\FolderB' -File | Sort-Object Name

if ($prefixes.Count -gt 0) {
    $batchSize = [Math]::Floor($filesB.Count / $prefixes.Count)  # number of items to receive the same prefix
    $offset    = 0
    foreach ($prefix in $prefixes) {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $batchSize; $i++) {
            $index = $offset * $batchSize + $i
            $filesB[$index] | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}_{1}' -f $prefix, $filesB[$index].Name) -WhatIf
        }
        $offset++
    }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "No files found in FolderA. This would result in a 'Divide by Zero error'"
}
```

Result:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-A.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-A.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-B.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-B.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-C.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-C.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-D.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-D.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-E.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-E.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-F.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\67890-DEF_NO_1111-F.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-G.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\67890-DEF_NO_1111-G.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-H.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\67890-DEF_NO_1111-H.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-I.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\67890-DEF_NO_1111-I.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-J.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\67890-DEF_NO_1111-J.txt".
```

---

**Update**

From your comments, you need to change the extension for the renamed files into `.csv` aswell, but also want to rename any files that remain because they did not 'fit' in the batches.

The code below will do both:

```
# get an array of prefixes, taken from the file names in FolderA
$prefixes = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\FolderA' -File | ForEach-Object { $_.BaseName -replace '^ID_' } | Sort-Object
# get an array of FileInfo objects of all files in FolderB
$filesB = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\FolderB' -File | Sort-Object Name

if ($prefixes.Count -gt 0) {
    $batchSize = [Math]::Floor($filesB.Count / $prefixes.Count)  # number of items to receive the same prefix
    $offset    = 0
    foreach ($prefix in $prefixes) {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $batchSize; $i++) {
            $index = $offset * $batchSize + $i
            $filesB[$index] | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}_{1}.csv' -f $prefix, $filesB[$index].BaseName) -WhatIf
        }
        $offset++
    }
    # what to do with files that may remain?
    # this is one way of renaming them using random prefixes from the $prefixes array
    $remaining = $filesB.Count - $offset * $batchSize
    if ($remaining) {
        Write-Host "Renaming $remaining item(s) randomly" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    while ($remaining -gt 0) {
        $randomPrefix = Get-Random $prefixes
        $filesB[-$remaining] | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}_{1}.csv' -f $randomPrefix, $filesB[-$remaining].BaseName) -WhatIf
        $remaining--
    }
}
else {
    Write-Warning "No files found in FolderA. This would result in a 'Divide by Zero error'"
}
```

Using 11 files in FolderB (11 does not divide evenly by 2, so there is a remaining file to rename), The result is:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-A.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-A.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-B.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-B.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-C.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-C.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-D.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-D.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-E.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-E.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-F.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\67890-DEF_NO_1111-F.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-G.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\67890-DEF_NO_1111-G.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-H.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\67890-DEF_NO_1111-H.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-I.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\67890-DEF_NO_1111-I.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-J.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\67890-DEF_NO_1111-J.csv".
Renaming 1 item(s) randomly
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\FolderB\NO_1111-K.txt Destination: D:\FolderB\12345-ABC_NO_1111-K.csv".
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch from the `Rename-Item` cmdlet(s) if you are satisfied with the results.

Comment: WOW.. Thank you so much. It works. But I have a problem if the total file in folder A divide folder B has Mod, the mod can not rename it. And also need to change the extension file after rename it. Could you please help me $Theo

Comment: @Job Sure, what do you want the new extension to be? And what do you want to do with files that remain (the Mod ones) ?

Comment: the extension to be .csv and if files has remain, it will assign randomly. @Theo

Comment: @job By _assign randomly_ you mean the code should rename them using a random name from the filenames in FolderA ?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.

Comment: @Job Ok, I have added new code to change the extension during the rename and also randomly assign prefixes to any files that remain.

Comment: Hi @Theo it still does not work. the remains name became `I_NO_1111-A.csv` , `I_NO_1111-B.csv` . this is the format
it just pick the firs word from folder A

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196623/discussion-between-job-and-theo).

Comment: @job I changed the way to get the random prefix. Strange however, because in my test cases, both methods perform just fine..

Comment: It return me an error `Get-Random : Cannot convert value "12345-ABC" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format." ` @Theo and the remain file also dont rename

Comment: @job _convert to Int32_ ?? What version of PowerShell are you on? $randomPrefix is simply a string that should replace the `{0}` part of yhe new filename.. As said, both this and the previous method work for me. I'm on Win 7, PS version 5.1

Comment: I use this way `Get-Random -InputObject` it works. But the remain always assign to last file of folder A

Comment: @Job Try `$randomPrefix = $prefixes | Get-Random`

Comment: Yes, it works as well. But the same case that mine, All of the remain always assign to the last file in the folder A

Comment: @job In the PowerShell console, enter `"a","b" | Get-Random` a few times. You should see `a` or `b` returned randomly

Comment: Oh, okay. got it. Thanks a lot @Theo. 
If you dont mind, could you please help me to give an advice for my other question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57089506/11099245 
Thanks in advance