# How to do looping for checking an existing folder with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to decide which folder that I need to choose based on my data, then if I can't find it, it will show the GUI for waiting and do looping to check it. I try this code, I can find the folder, but when I can't find it once I want to show the GUI it returns some error.

This is how I checking the folder

```
function FIND {
    Write-Host "call the function that can call the GUI.ps1 script"

        $Path = "D:\Process"
        Write-Host "Starting Mapping SSID and Finding Job"
        $SSID_Unit = "111dddddfafafesa"

        Try{
            $Path_Job = (Get-Item (Get-ChildItem "$Path\*\SSID_LST" | Select-String -Pattern "$SSID_Unit").Path).Directory.FullName

            $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Exists   = $true
                FileName = $Path_Job.FullName
                Attempts = 1
            }
            Write-Host "Job'$($global:Result.FileName)' Exists. Found after $($global:Result.Attempts) attempts." -ForegroundColor Green
            Write-Host "Continue to Assigned Job"
            Pause
        } Catch {
            Write-Host "Waiting for the jobss"
            & D:\X\Wait_GUI.ps1  -Path $Path_Job -MaxAttempts 20
            Write-Host "Job not found after $($global:Result.Attempts) attempts." -ForegroundColor Red

        }   
    }
    FIND
```

This is the GUI

```
    Param (   
        [string]$Path = '*.*',
        [string]$MaxAttempts = 5
    ) 

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

    # set things up for the timer
    $script:nAttempts = 0
    $timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    $timer.Interval = 1000  # 1 second
    $timer.Add_Tick({
        $global:Result = $null
        $script:nAttempts++
        $Path_Job = Get-Item -Path $Path
        if ($Path_Job) {
            $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Exists   = $true
                FileName = $Path_Job.FullName
                Attempts = $script:nAttempts
            }
            $timer.Dispose()
            $Form.Close()
        }
        elseif ($script:nAttempts -ge $MaxAttempts) {
            $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Exists   = $false
                FileName = ''
                Attempts = $script:nAttempts
            }
            $timer.Dispose()
            $Form.Close()
        }
    })

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

    $Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.ClientSize                 = '617,418'
    $Form.text                       = "AutoGM"
    $Form.BackColor                  = "#8b572a"
    $Form.TopMost                    = $false
    $Form.WindowState                = 'Maximized'

    $Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label1.text                     = "UNDER AUTOMATION PROCESS"
    $Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
    $Label1.width                    = 25
    $Label1.height                   = 10
    $Label1.Anchor                   = 'top,right,bottom,left'

    $Label1.ForeColor                = "#ffffff"
    $Label1.Anchor                   = "None"
    $Label1.TextAlign                = "MiddleCenter"

    $Label2                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label2.text                     = "Waiting for the job..."
    $Label2.AutoSize                 = $true
    $Label2.width                    = 25
    $Label2.height                   = 10

    $Label2.ForeColor                = "#ffffff"
    $Label2.Anchor                   = "None"
    $Label2.TextAlign                = "MiddleCenter"

    $Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Label2))

    [void]$Form.Show()
    # Write-Host $Form.Height
    # Write-Host $Form.Width

    $Label1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Form.Width*0.35), ($Form.Height*0.4))
    $Label2.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($form.Width*0.43), ($Form.Height*0.5))

    $L_S = (($Form.Width/2) - ($Form.Height / 2)) / 15
    $Label1.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, $L_S, style=Bold"
    $Label2.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, $L_S, style=Bold"

    $Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Label2))
    # start the timer as soon as the dialog is visible
    $Form.Add_Shown({ $timer.Start() })

    $Form.Visible = $false
    [void]$Form.ShowDialog()

    # clean up when done
    $Form.Dispose()
```

if not found, it return this

```
    Waiting for the jobss
    Job not found after 1 attempts.
```

and the GUI is not shown

Comment: That error being ... *what?*

Comment: @Job This is really the first part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57098199/9898643) of your previous question, above the **Update** code, because then you specified new requirements. Seems in this question you're back to that first idea.. Only the form changed a little and the file paths. What is the error you are getting with this?

Comment: Hi @Theo, I updated the code reference to your previous answer. But it still return an error, could you please help me. Thanks

Comment: It is a bit unclear what exactly you are looking for.. A file that has a string "1010" somewhere in its contents, or a folder by that name or... The error message is simple enough. You are testing if something exists, and if not you show the GUI with the path parameter set to this `$null` valued variable `$Path_Job`. Inside the GUI you should perform the exact same test as you do outside of the form. Please explain a bit more what it is the function is looking for.

Comment: @Theo I updated the script to call the GUI, it does not return error, but It can not execute the GUI. Is there any wrong with the GUI script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, first of all, you are using different tests for the file and/or directory in the code and in the GUI. Furthermore, you call the GUI.ps1 file with a path set to a `$null` value.

I would change your code to something like this:

```
$Path      = "D:\Process\*\SSID_LST\*"  # the path to look for files
$SSID_Unit = "111dddddfafafesa"         # the Search pattern to look for inside the files

function Test-FileWithGui {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [string]$Pattern,
        [int]$MaxAttempts = 5
    )

    Write-Host "Starting Mapping SSID and Finding Job"

    # set up an 'empty' $global:Result object to return on failure
    $global:Result = '' | Select-Object @{Name = 'Exists'; Expression = {$false}}, FileName, Directory, @{Name = 'Attempts'; Expression = {1}}

    # test if the given path is valid. If not, exit the function
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Warning "Path '$Path' does not exist."
        return
    }
    # try and find the first file that contains your search pattern
    $file = Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern $Pattern -SimpleMatch -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -First 1

    if ($file) {
        $file = Get-Item -Path $file.Path

        $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Exists    = $true
            FileName  = $file.FullName
            Directory = $file.DirectoryName
            Attempts  = 1
        }
    }
    else {
        & "D:\GUI.ps1" -Path $Path -Pattern $Pattern -MaxAttempts $MaxAttempts
    }
}

# call the function that can call the GUI.ps1 script
Test-FileWithGui -Path $Path -Pattern $SSID_Unit -MaxAttempts 20

# show the $global:Result object with all properties
$global:Result | Format-List

# check the Global result object
if ($global:Result.Exists) {
    Write-Host "File '$($global:Result.FileName)' Exists. Found after $($global:Result.Attempts) attempts." -ForegroundColor Green
}
else {
    Write-Host "File not found after $($global:Result.Attempts) attempts." -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Next the GUI file.
As you are now searching for a file that contains some text, you need a third parameter to call this named `Pattern`.

Inside the GUI file we perform the exact same test as we did in the code above, using the parameter `$Pattern` as search string:

```
Param (   
    [string]$Path,
    [string]$Pattern,
    [int]$MaxAttempts = 5
) 

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

# set things up for the timer
$script:nAttempts = 0
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000  # 1 second
$timer.Add_Tick({
    $global:Result = $null
    $script:nAttempts++

    # use the same test as you did outside of the GUI
    # try and find the first file that contains your search pattern
    $file = Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern $Pattern -SimpleMatch -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -First 1

    if ($file) {
        $file = Get-Item -Path $file.Path

        $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Exists    = $true
            FileName  = $file.FullName
            Directory = $file.DirectoryName
            Attempts  = $script:nAttempts
        }
        $timer.Dispose()
        $Form.Close()
    }
    elseif ($script:nAttempts -ge $MaxAttempts) {
        $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Exists    = $false
            FileName  = $null
            Directory = $null
            Attempts  = $script:nAttempts
        }
        $script:nAttempts = 0
        $timer.Dispose()
        $Form.Close()
    }
})

$Form             = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize  = '617,418'
$Form.Text        = "AutoGM"
$Form.BackColor   = "#8b572a"
$Form.TopMost     = $true
$Form.WindowState = 'Maximized'

# I have removed $Label2 because it is easier to use 
# just one label here and Dock it to Fill.
$Label1           = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.Text      = "UNDER AUTOMATION PROCESS`r`n`r`nWaiting for the job..."
$Label1.AutoSize  = $false
$Label1.Dock      = 'Fill'
$Label1.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
$Label1.ForeColor = "#ffffff"

$L_S = (($Form.Width/2) - ($Form.Height / 2)) / 10
$Label1.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, $L_S, style=Bold"

$Form.controls.Add($Label1)

# start the timer as soon as the dialog is visible
$Form.Add_Shown({ $timer.Start() })

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()

# clean up when done
$Form.Dispose()
```

The results during testing came out like below

If the file was found within the set `MaxAttempts` tries:

> ```
> Starting Mapping SSID and Finding Job
>
>
> Exists    : True
> FileName  : D:\Process\test\SSID_LST\blah.txt
> Directory : D:\Process\test\SSID_LST
> Attempts  : 7
>
>
>
> File 'D:\Process\test\SSID_LST\blah.txt' Exists. Found after 7 attempts.
> ```

When the file was NOT found:

> ```
> Starting Mapping SSID and Finding Job
>
>
> Exists    : False
> FileName  : 
> Directory : 
> Attempts  : 20
>
>
>
> File not found after 20 attempts.
> ```

If even the folder `$Path` was not found, the output is

> ```
> Starting Mapping SSID and Finding Job
> WARNING: Path 'D:\Process\*\SSID_LST\*' does not exist.
>
>
> Exists    : False
> FileName  : 
> Directory : 
> Attempts  : 1
>
>
>
> File not found after 1 attempts.
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi @Theo.. I tried this, but it always return this `Starting Mapping SSID and Finding Job
WARNING: Path 'D:\Process\*\SSID_LST\*' does not exist.


Exists    : False
FileName  :
Directory :
Attempts  : 1

File not found after 1 attempts.`
Even the string $SSID_Unit exist in the SSID_LST file, it always return not found
And the GUI is Not shown if it is not found

Comment: Hi @Theo, I updated the code this part
`$Path      = Get-ChildItem "D:\Process\*\SSID_LST\"  # the path to look for files
$SSID_Unit = "1309"         # the Search pattern to look for inside the files
function Test-FileWithGui {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        $Path,`
I add `Get-ChildItem` and I remove the `[string] in the $Path`
In the GUI I also remove [string] in the $Path
I use this `Param (   
    $Path,
    [string]$Pattern,
    [int]$MaxAttempts = 5
) `
and it works.

Comment: @Job Good to hear you've got it working. For me, without having your original files, it was hard to test it all out.

Comment: Hi @Theo I found the error, cannot bind argument to parameter 'pattern' because its an empty string

Comment: @Job. That error is **NOT in my code**. You _really_ need to start learning something about [Function parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) and how to use them. The `$Path` parameter is designed to be a `[string]`. If you send it the _result_ of `Get-ChildItem "D:\Process\*\SSID_LST\"`, you're not sending a string, but an array of `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` objects.

Comment: @Job Next, you set the string to search for `$SSID_Unit = "1309"` _OUTSIDE_ the function, which is perfectly fine. However, _INSIDE_ the function and also inside the GUI script, it is then called `$Pattern`. The script has no idea what `$SSID_Unit` is.

Comment: Hi @Theo I got it. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Theo, I have a problem when I execute this code, then after all this code done, I do restart/reboot, and do some process, but I can not get the variable folder of SSID_LST. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi @Theo, I have a problem when I execute this code, then after all this code done, I do restart/reboot, and do some process, but I can not get the variable folder of SSID_LST. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198237/discussion-between-job-and-theo).

Comment: Hi @Theo.. I found one problem with your answer. Once it can not find the match SSID, it will show the GUI. But when I add new folder and inside the folder exist the match SSID, it still looking for th SSID match only inside the first folder. It does not check in the new folder that I create. Do you have any idea about it. Thanks