# How to keep updating a path folder for mapping file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I have some folder, inside those folder has a file call it SSID_LST. Inside the SSID_LST file there is a string. I want to match the SSID_LST with $SSIDUnit. If it is match, It will return the folder path. If its not match, it will show the GUI and do looping to check which SSID_LST match with the $SSIDUnit.
In this code, I can get the folder which match with $SSIDUnit. But once it is not matched and show GUI for doing check match $SSIDUnit, and then I drop a new folder contain of SSID_LST and inside the SSID_LST match with $SSIDUnit, it does not check the SSID_LST in new folder that I drop. It only checking the old folder.
Its like how to update the $Path to check the existing folder to find SSID_LST file.

I have to do updating in this part, if there is a new folder drop to $JobFolder, it will include the new folder for checking the SSID_LST file.

```
$Path = Get-ChildItem "$JobFolder\*\$SSIDName\"
Write-Output "Path SSID : $Path"
```

Anyone has an idea about it?
I refer to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57524097/11099245

```cs
function Test-FileWithGui {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [string]$Pattern,
        [int]$MaxAttempts = 50
    )

    # set up an 'empty' $global:Result object to return on failure
    $global:Result = '' | Select-Object @{Name = 'Exists'; Expression = {$false}}, FileName, Directory, @{Name = 'Attempts'; Expression = {1}}
    # try and find the first file that contains your search pattern
    $file = Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern $Pattern -SimpleMatch -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -First 1

    if ($file) {
        $file = Get-Item -Path $file.Path

        $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Exists    = $true
            FileName  = $file.FullName
            Directory = $file.DirectoryName
            Attempts  = 1
        }
    } else {
        & ".\Wait_GUI.ps1" -Path $Path -Pattern $Pattern -MaxAttempts $MaxAttempts
    }
}

function MAPPING_JOB {
    $SSIDUnit = "1234"
    Write-Output "Strating mapping the job folder"
    $JobFolder = "D:\Process"
    $SSIDName = "SSID_LST"
    Write-Output "SSIDNAME : $SSIDName"

    $Path = Get-ChildItem "$JobFolder\*\$SSIDName\"  # the path to look for files
    Write-Output "Path SSID : $Path"

    $Wait_Job = "1000"
    Test-FileWithGui -Path $Path -Pattern "$SSIDUnit" -MaxAttempts $Wait_Job
    Pause

    # show the $global:Result object with all properties
    $global:Result | Format-List

    # check the Global result object
    if ($global:Result.Exists) {
        Write-Output "File '$($global:Result.FileName)' Exists. Found after $($global:Result.Attempts) attempts." -ForegroundColor Green

        Write-Output "Continue to check the job.que"
        pause
        CALL_JOBQUE
    } else {
        Write-Output "File not found after $($global:Result.Attempts) attempts." -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Output "Go to Reboot"
        pause
    }
}
MAPPING_JOB
```

GUI Script

```
Param (   
    $Path,
    [string]$Pattern,
    [int]$MaxAttempts = 10
) 

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

# set things up for the timer
$script:nAttempts = 0
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000  # 1 second
$timer.Add_Tick({
    $global:Result = $null
    $script:nAttempts++

    # use the same test as you did outside of the GUI
    # try and find the first file that contains your search pattern
    $file = Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern $Pattern -SimpleMatch -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -First 1

    if ($file) {
        $file = Get-Item -Path $file.Path

        $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Exists    = $true
            FileName  = $file.FullName
            Directory = $file.DirectoryName
            Attempts  = $script:nAttempts
        }
        $timer.Dispose()
        $Form.Close()
    } elseif ($script:nAttempts -ge $MaxAttempts) {
        $global:Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Exists    = $false
            FileName  = $null
            Directory = $null
            Attempts  = $script:nAttempts
        }
        $script:nAttempts = 0
        $timer.Dispose()
        $Form.Close()
    }
})

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.WindowState = 'Maximized'
$img = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile('.\ATGM.png')
$form.BackgroundImage = $img
$form.BackgroundImageLayout = 'Center'
$Form.BackColor = "#ffffff"

$Form.Add_Shown({ $timer.Start() })
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()

# clean up when done
$Form.Dispose()
```

Comment: Long code fragments, very little description in (for me) hard to understand English, this is ***not*** what I'd call a [mcve]. Also some previous Q&A you have to read to understand the question, maybe you should redo the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I have to remove `Get-ChildItem` in this part `$Path = Get-ChildItem "$JobFolder\*\$SSIDName\"` it should be `$Path = "$JobFolder\*\$SSIDName\"`